# Python CSV import for Django Heroku App not functioning properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku, django-models

I'm currently getting this error when I try uploading my CSV file into my Django Heroku CRM app, the app is also using Herokus Postgres DB:

```
Unable to upload file. ValidationError(['“” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.'])
&
Unable to upload file. ValidationError(['“1995-03-28” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.'])
```

Here is the codeblock that I am currently using:

```
 - views.py

class LeadImportView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = LeadImportForm
    template_name = 'import_leads.html'
    success_url = '/dashboard/leads/'
    def form_valid(self, form):
            df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')))
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                lead = Lead()
                ...
                dob = row['DOB']
                if str(dob).strip() == 'nan' or str(dob).strip() == "":
                    try:
                        lead.dob = None
                    except ValidationError:
                        lead.dob = None
                else:
                    lead.dob = dob
                ...
                lead.save()
            
            messages.success(self.request, 'Leads successfully imported.')
            # return redirect('leads:lead-list')
            return super().form_valid(form)

 - forms.py

class LeadForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    dob = forms.DateField()
    ...

 - models.py

class Lead(models.Model):
    ...
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

As you can see, if the CSV dob value is blank, then it should equal a None value in the DB. However, no matter if the DOB is filled appropriately or empty, the code still errors out. Any insight helps. Also, I would prefer the date format to be MM/DD/YYYY but i'm not entirely sure how to override djangos default %Y%m%d

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the problem is coming from your CSV which contains the ” signs. This is known as the right double qutation mark (https://symbl.cc/en/201D/).
The parser will have trouble understanding this.

You can use `strptime` to understand this format like:

```py
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("“1995-03-28”", "“%Y-%m-%d”")
```

with which you will obtain a date or in your case:

```py
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(dob, "“%Y-%m-%d”")
```

or

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(dob, "“%Y-%m-%d”").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

to obtain a string.